# Parsing href using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing

I have web scraping using python that gets this code from the site:

```
<a href="javascript:document.frmMain.action.value='display_physician_info';document.frmMain.PhysicianID.value=1234567;document.frmMain.submit();" title="For more information, click here.">JOHN, DOE</a>
```

I want to parse the specific value of href like the value of **PhysicianID** which is **1234567** inside *"document.frmMain.PhysicianID.value"*

Currently I'm getting the whole href text something like this:

```
for i in soup.select('.data'):
     name = i.find('a', attrs = {'title': 'For more information, click here.'})
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting in `href` itself is easy with `BeautifulSoup` once you've got the link itself:

```
href = name['href']
```

Then you can use regex with the `re` module:

```
import re
match = re.search(r'document.frmMain.PhysicianID.value=\d*;', href).group()
value = re.search(r'\d+', match).group()
print(value) #prints 1234567
```

Putting it all together with your code:

```
import re
for i in soup.select('.data'):
    name = i.find('a', attrs = {'title': 'For more information, click here.'})
    match = re.search(r'document.frmMain.PhysicianID.value=\d*;', href).group()
    value = re.search(r'\d+', match).group()
    print(value) #prints 1234567
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without regex:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<a href="javascript:document.frmMain.action.value='display_physician_info';document.frmMain.PhysicianID.value=1234567;document.frmMain.submit();" title="For more information, click here.">JOHN, DOE</a>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("a")['href'].split("PhysicianID.value=")[1].split(";")[0]
print(item)
```

Output:

```
1234567
```